# What’s the grammar of "For those whose stories they are"?

Tags: grammar

> Minister for Foreign Affairs [Penny Wong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_Wong#Albanese_Government_(2022%E2%80%93present)) has urged the UK to confront its colonial past.

Speaking at King’s College’s Centre for Grand Strategy, Senator Wong highlighted the UK’s role in the Indo-Pacific region both now and in its history.

She described her own family’s history and its relationship with British colonialism.

Ms Wong said, “Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – **for those whose stories they are**, and for those who hear them.”

I can understand the meaning of the words in bold. But the grammar eludes me. Please elucidate for me.

Comment: What specifically about the grammar of that string has you confused? What does your analysis look like so far? Please include details to clarify the problem. As it stands your question is vague and may invite a general lecture on all sorts of things - prepositional phrases, pronouns, relative clauses, etc.

Comment: @ DW256 you are right. But I'm not sure how to phrase it. For me, it sounds more natural if the line is changed to "Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those whose stories as such", instead of using the original "they are". Am I right in thinking this? It is because of this weirdness, I want the grammar explained behind the line. Not pronouns, more like sentence structure.

Comment: The technical term for the rule that fronts the prepositional phrase _for those_ before the relative word _whose_ is "_Pied-Piping_". It can apply recursively to noun phrases as well as prepositional phrases, e.g: _these books, **the height of the lettering on the covers of which** is set by law,_

Comment: *"Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those whose stories as such"* Really? That just looks wrong to me. I can't figure out what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: I'd give the phrasing a pass for the sound bite it is. Exploitation tales are uncomfortable to own if the stories are yours, or if you have to hear them.

Comment: *Let he who is without sin cast the first stone...  for he whose stone is cast first must not be a sinner*.

Comment: I think it is ***plagiarism*** not quoting the part that has been copied. ***The first four paragraphs*** are also [here](https://nit.com.au/03-02-2023/4878/penny-wong-urges-britain-to-face-the-legacy-of-i) (primary source some press release?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen isn't the identity of the speaker clear who? The formatting, block quotes and speech marks, also shows that the OP is not claiming to be the author. They didn't write the name of the source (e.g. The Guardian, TFT), but they did write *who* the source is.

Answer (score 9):

> *Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable* – [*for those whose*
> *stories they are,*] *and* [*for those who hear them*].

The bracketed elements form a coordination of two preposition phrases linked by "and", each headed by the prep "for". In each coordinate "for" has a noun phrase as its complement, i.e. "those whose stories they are", and "those who hear them.”

These noun phases contain, respectively, the relative clause "whose stories they are", and "who hear them" functioning as modifier of "those", which is understood as "the people".

In the first coordinate the genitive noun phrase "whose stories” functions as predicative complement of "are", where "whose" is anaphoric to "those". In the second coordinate "them" is anaphoric to "stories".

Comment: I believe that in the first coordinate only "whose" (not "whose stories") is anaphoric to "those," right?

Comment: @alphabet Quite right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

> Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those [whose stories they are], and for those [who hear them].

[Both relative clauses] combine with *those* (= "those people") to form noun phrases.

Both *they* and *them* refer to *such stories*. So the first [RC] means "such stories are their stories", where "their" refers to *those* (= "those people").

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this question. It's a very interesting question.

We are discussing the grammar that was used in diplomatic speech from January 2023.

First let's reproduce the text from the speech:

> such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those whose
> stories they are, and for those who hear them.

I think the key to answering this question is understanding what the pronouns "they" and "them" refer to. [1]

The pronouns "they" and "them" both refer to "such stories", the subject of the sentence.

Since "they" is the predicate of a linking verb, it takes the nominative case. [2]

Since "them" is the direct object of the verb "to hear", it takes the accusative case.

So just remember that the pronouns "they" and "them" both refer to the subject of the sentence. The subject of the sentence is "such stories".

We can even try substituting "such stories" for the pronouns "they" and "them", and see how it looks.

> such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those whose
> stories such stories are, and for those who hear such stories.

It makes sense this way, but it is a little wordy. One can see why the author opted for pronouns.

---

Footnotes:

[1] Since "they" and "them" are pronouns, we know they must represent a noun or a noun phrase. It is useful to ask what these pronouns represent.

[2] The predicate of a linking verb can often be in the nominative case. For example, *"We were told the mother would be with her child," said the magi. "I am she," answered Mary.* You can see how in this dialogue, the word "she" is in the nominative case. This is a lot like the example from the diplomatic speech where the word "they" is in the nominative case.

Answer (score -4):

I think this is not phrased properly, that it is awkward English; it seems to me that what this writer was trying to say by the means of "for those whose stories they are"  was  "for those who recognize themselves in the stories".

The problem : "whose stories" stands for  "the stories of someone", and logically "those" is that someone, but then "they" is a subject without a logical referent. The referent cannot be "those"; it cannot be "whose stories" since there is then a redundancy; it has to be "such stories" and that is not logical.

- <s>Ms Wong said, “Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those whose stories such storie are, and for those who hear them.</s>
- Ms Wong said, “Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those who recognize themselves in them, and for those who hear them.

---

*Correction of the above after comment from [user Nick Matteo](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/37019/nick-matteo) —  The nominal phrase under scrutiny appears to be logical after all, but the result still seems contrived.*

Ms Wong said, “Such stories can sometimes feel uncomfortable – for those  [ the stories of those ] [ such stories ] are and …  (*initial inversion*)

Such stories feel uncomfortable for those (who are such that) [such stories] [are] [the stories of those] (*removal of initial inversion*)

Such stories feel uncomfortable for those (who are such that) [such stories] [are] [their stories]  (*correct formulation, even if, however, too complicated*)

In conclusion I'd say that the construction is logical, but it seems rather contrived, and it seems better to replace it with something simpler that achieves the same goal.

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe. The referent of "they" is the stories again, as in "for those whose stories the stories are."

Comment: @NickMatteo You should carry out your reasoning to the end and see what you get after a replacement:  "for those whose stories the stories are". It'scomplete  gibberish.

Comment: No, it's fine. "Marbles are fun, for those whose marbles they are."

Comment: @NickMatteo Interesting, you seem to be familiar with this construction… However, "are" is used elliptically here; what is the omission? Stories? It gives "for those whose stories the stories are stories". I don't agree, it is awful, ungrammatical.

Comment: @NickMatteo There is an error in my last comment: "are" is not used elliptically, the subject complement figures in the clause. Sorry for that.